# Receive side scaling (RSS) based on just one field inside UDP payload

Tags: networking, network-programming, load-balancing, dpdk, offloading

I have an issue with HW-offloaded balancing of network packets between CPU cores on DPDK.
In my case I have only several endpoints whose number is less than the number of CPU cores I have.
All the incoming traffic is local (not transit/forward), so I can't balance it based on IP/UDP header fields, i.e. 5-tuple or 2-tuple [RSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/introduction-to-receive-side-scaling) doesn't fit my needs.

There is great news, my node is engaged in tunneling over UDP and receives packets, where UDP payload contains some tunnel identifier (4 bytes). Round-robin RSS is not suitable, because buffers associated with tunnels are per-core.
So I think that packets can be **dynamicaly** balanced by mentioned "tunnel ID", i.e. based on only one 4-byte field inside UDP payload so that packets with the same ID will arrive to the same CPU core. <s>Hashing of course is not necessary for this</s> (perhaps my logical mistake).

So my question - is there any way to configure such a dynamic balancing (based on hash of one 4-byte field by offset inside UDP payload or hash of this field + some other fields, e.g. source IP) between CPU cores on some modern NIC (Intel x710 or Mellanox ConnectX-4 the most interesting)? If there is, please give an advice on how to configure this.

**UPD**

I concluded that hashing is not necessary, but the conclusion is probably erroneous. I don't know the tunnel IDs in advance, they come in the packet headers.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to DPDK and I haven't explored tunneling so not sure whether my thing is gonna useful for you.

From my experience, what we did was run a polling thread that actually receives all packets and then routes them (UDP packets) to different processing threads (following certain algorithm) running on a different core. the basic concept is from the "client-server multiprocess model" which is an official example for DPDK

Our work is in VOIP field so we wanted to make sure that whenever a call starts, the following all UDP packets of that call should be processed in same core for better cache locality. And the core distribution should happen only when a core reaches it's processing limit. so for the signalling packet we assigned an id for that call which later I used to redirect all packets to that specific core thread.

Comment: This is called "programmatic RSS", it changes the processing model from run-to-completion to pipeline and has some overhead. hardware-offloaded balancing is obviuosly faster... I want to enable hardware-offloaded RSS